# How to put exponents (power symbol) in tables made using the gtable package?

Tags: r, gtable

```
tab_header(
    title = expression(Ni^"2+" ~ Remediation),
    subtitle = "Trials 1- 4",
    )
```

[image: 2+ is not shown as a power]

I would like to know how to get the 2+ to come as a power.

Here, I tried the expression function, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's enough for the `"2+"` to show up in superscript, you could use the `<sup>` tag in HTML.

```
gt(df) %>%
  tab_header(
    title = html("Ni<sup>2+</sup> ~ Remediation"),
    subtitle = "Trials 1- 4"
  )
```